# saving and reading a file of integers in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

i have an array like: `int array[500][2];`
suppose

```
array[0][0]=1;  array[0][1]=2;
array[1][0]=2;  array[1][1]=4;
array[2][0]=4;  array[2][1]=6;
```

....
i'd like to write a file and read after saving it...
do i have to pass all values to NSString?
thanks

Comment: and please use formatting for the post. Do u expect people to help u, if u not even spend the time to format code correctly?

Comment: @vikingosegundo Correcting people while using 'text speak' might not produce the results that you expect.

Comment: @Tim Post what is 'text speak'?

Comment: @vikingosegundo abbreviation like 'u' instead of 'you'

Comment: ah, ok. I was chatting. It must have slipped in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do i have to pass all values to
>   NSNumber

No. You could use fread()/fwrite(), if you wanted.  Or you could encode as XML.

Not enough context to be more specific.